# show notification from google chat activity only when activity is in background

Tags: android

This is a Google Chat application. When I get a message from Google Chat I want to show it in the status bar as a notification when the activity is in background.

I tried setting boolean values in the `onPause()` method but it did not work.

```
public void addMessage(String chatid, String msg) {
    // I want to the execute this line only when the activity is in background
    notify.getCurrentActivity(getApplicationContext(), msg, fromName, chatid);
}

public void getCurrentActivity(Context context, String msg){
    showNotification(context, msg, fromName, fromChatID);
}
```

Comment: use a service + broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

I find out solution myself

private int key;    // Declare as global

protected void onPause

{

key=1;

super.onpause();

}

protected void onResume{

key=0;

super.onResume();

}

public void addMessage(String chatid, String msg) {

if(key==1)

{

notify.getCurrentActivity(getApplicationContext(), msg, fromName, chatid);

}

}